# Cross Domain JavaScript parent location setting firefox error

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, cross-domain

Here is the case:
page A contains iframe B, B contains iframe C, A and B are under the same domain, C under another. 
C tries to reset parent B's location with extra information following "#" to solve cross domain communication using Fragment Id Messaging. 
IE6/7/8 just works fine with this case, while Firefox blocks **parent.location** setting with error message [**Access to property denied" code: "1010**].
But if B is the top window, meaning there is no A, Firefox lives too.

It's strange to me... Could you guys please help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Historically, any window could change the location of any other window.  This turned out to be a problem because, among other things, it meant embedding a login iframe in a window was unsafe (because then a malicious site could replace the login iframe with a spoofed version).  Over time further restrictions have been applied to location changes to browser windows, until now, when [HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#security-1) and most browsers have reached common agreement on [the ancestor policy](http://seclab.stanford.edu/websec/frames/navigation/).  In a nutshell, paraphrasing the HTML5 specification, a window A can change the location of another window B iff:

- the locations of A and B have the same origin, which is to say they have the same scheme, host, and port (http, stackoverflow.com, 80 for example), or
- B is a top-level window, and A is a window in a frame nested at some depth within B (direct child, child of a child, etc.), or
- B is a window opened using `window.open` and A can change the location of the window that opened B (so B is a popup opened by A, by a popup window opened by A, or at greater depth), or
- B isn't a top-level window, but its parent window, or its parent's parent window, or at some similar amount of parentage the locations of that window and A are same-origin

(Same origin is more complicated than this, but the embedded description above catches its essence and covers the most common cases.)

Under this policy, C may change the location of A, and A may change the location of B or C, but C may not change the location of B.  If you need to work around this, then you should change your page A's location to something that changes B as appropriate; alternately, you could [ask your page B to change its own location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage).

Hopefully that's informative, if not necessarily helpful.  The browser security model wasn't so much *designed* as *evolved*, and only with recent work in HTML5 is it really being precisely nailed down to address these cross-browser inconsistencies.

All that said, I'm surprised IE7 and IE8 work for you -- it was my understanding the above policy was primarily based upon the policy IE7 implemented.

Comment: thanks for your clear and beautiful answer, i will reconsider my solution on this.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  It should be noted that window.postMessage that you link to works in all modern browsers, but the syntax in IE is a little different.  I posted a question similar to this and ended up answering it myself.  Here is my answer which has a simple cross-browser example implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860470/is-there-any-way-for-an-iframe-to-change-the-top-windows-url/1861054#1861054

Answer (score 0):

From C you can access B's window using `window.top`.

Try, `var B = window.top; B.location = "...";`

Comment: if using window.top from C, i got A rather than B, but i don't want to reset A's location...