# Changing parent window's URL from IFrame

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe

I have a situation where I have web apps on two different servers, where App1 contains App2 in an IFrame.  Any links in App2 can have `target="_parent"` attribute, which allow those links to open in the top window.  However, I can't find any way to get the same behavior in Javascript.  I found [this page](http://av5.com/docs/changing-parent-window-s-url-from-iframe-content.html), which *claims* that the child frame can call javascript on the parent frame using `parent.foo()`, but that doesn't seem to work in IE8 or FF3.5.  I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157233/cross-domain-javascript-parent-location-setting-firefox-error) which explains how this security model works.  But it seems odd that I can't do in Javascript what I can do with a simple `<a>` tag.  **Is there any workaround to this at all?** I know about [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage), but (as far as I know) this only works in Firefox.

---

### Example

#### server1/test.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myCallback(foo) {
  alert(foo);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://server2/test2.htm" width="400" height="150"></iframe>
</body></html>
```

#### server2/test2.html

```
<html><body>
<script>
function clickit() {
  parent.document.location = "http://www.google.com"; //not allowed
  parent.myCallback("http://www.google.com"); //not allowed
}
</script>
<p>This should be in an iFrame!</p>
<p><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_parent">normal link (works)</a></p>
<p><a href="javascript:clickit()">javascript link</a></p>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK I did more investigation, and it appears that postMessage works in all modern browsers, even IE (with the caveat that IE has a slightly different way of doing it).  Here's how I got it to work (tested on WinXP in IE8, FF3.5, Chrome 3.0, Safari 4 beta, Opera 9.64):

#### server1/test.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
  window.attachEvent("onmessage", receiveMessage);
else
  window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(e) {
  if(e.origin == "http://server2") //important for security
    if(e.data.indexOf('redirect:') == 0)
      document.location = e.data.substr(9);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://server2/test2.htm" width="400" height="150"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

#### server2/test2.htm

```
<html><body>
<script>
function clickit() {
  parent.postMessage('redirect:http://www.google.com', 'http://server1');
}
</script>
<p>This should be in an iFrame!</p>
<p><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_parent">normal link</a></p>
<p><a href="javascript:clickit()">javascript link</a></p>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple thing you can do is:
execute following from JavaScript code of iframe page

```
top.location = "https://www.google.co.in/";
```

this will change the location of window's URL to `https://www.google.co.in/`.

One more thing -This strategy can also be useful when you do not want that any one can inframe your site 
just write the above code in document ready part.

Comment: top.location.href = "https://www.google.co.in/" worked for me thanks

Comment: This solution does not work. Chrome is blocking redirect.

Answer (score 2):

No, and for good reason. If you need this, then you must run all communication through one of the two servers; for example, have server1 act as as a proxy for all requests for "server2/test2.html".

Answer (score 1):

If both parent and iframe are on subdomains under the same domain, you *may* be able to do something with the `document.domain` property. If both body and iframe are treated as being from the same origin, changing the location should be possible; I haven't tried this myself. Some reading [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

If the frames are on the same domain, you should be able to access the parent frame. Otherwise no, it's a security issue.

The only workaround that springs to mind would be to use AJAX to update a file on each of the servers, then check the contents of the opposite file server-side. You could do the same thing using a single database, if you allow connections from external domains.

This is all kind of overkill though, when you could simply pop-up a link in the frame and tell users to click it to continue.