# Opening jsp pages in an iframe from a drop-down menu

Tags: html, jsp

I'm creating an application in jsp & servlet. So I have created a home.jsp page it is a main page of an application and it contains a menu bar . When user clicks on menu item the following page should appear in my iframe and if user clicks on another menu item the selected page should appear in the same iframe.
I need a help.... The following code is creating a menu bar and menu item

```
    <li><a href="#">Master</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Customer.jsp">Customer</a></li>
            <li><a href="Suplier.jsp">Suplier</a></li>
            <li><a href="Item.jsp">Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Transaction</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Purchase.jsp">Purchase</a></li>
            <li><a href="Sales.jsp">Sales</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Contact.jsp">Contact</a></li>
```

After menu bar I have a iframe in which I want to show a menu item.
I don't know how do i do this. please help me out

Comment: You will need `jQuery` to do this easily. But you haven't added a tag in question of jQuery. Do you want a `jQuery` answer too?

Comment: Yes i don't mind jquery or javascript will be fine.

Comment: I have posted below the answer. You can check it. n If it helped please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to bind a function `onclick` of your `<a>` tag. Then using jQuery find the `href` of the `<a>` which is clicked, finally assign that `href` as `src` of your `iframe`

**HTML**

```
<li><a href="#">Master</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Customer.jsp">Customer</a></li>
        <li><a href="Suplier.jsp">Suplier</a></li>
        <li><a href="Item.jsp">Item</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Transaction</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Purchase.jsp">Purchase</a></li>
        <li><a href="Sales.jsp">Sales</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="Contact.jsp">Contact</a></li>
<br />
<iframe src="" height="300" width="500"></iframe>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function () {
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        $('iframe').attr('src', target);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here's a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4qaaqo87/)**. I just changed the `href` of first two items as example.

Comment: I tried and its not working .. can you do this in java script

Comment: thanks bro ... i got it.. it is a right ans. can u help me what i should do to grow my knowledge.

Comment: thanks .. i got it . I'LL c u in skype.. thanks again

Comment: hie.. syed ali taqi .. ur ans is working but it is not apearing in url.. do u have any other example.. And just now i created my Skype  id so can u provide me ur user id..

Comment: its `salitaqi` and I think you'll not get the `URL` if you use the `iFrame`

Comment: Its almost impossible to show `URL` in an `iFrame` or to to change to `URL` of current `Page` to `iFrame URL`. If you just want to get the `URL` and `alert or set it to a text field`. I think this will work `document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.location.href`

Comment: See these question. [Q1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860470/changing-parent-windows-url-from-iframe), [Q2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/136496/3621001).

Comment: now i have to creata a javascript also.. to call my current iframe value into url

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page). If this doesn't solve your problem please post it as **new question**. Long discusion shouldn't be done in comments at StackOverflow. If this doesn't solve your problem please post it as new question.